# I am unable to add extension to the firefox using geckodriver and javascript

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, firefox-addon, geckodriver

I want to attach my extension(.xpi file) to the Firefox using selenium.Post that I want to launch a url in the same. However I cannot attach the extension to the firefox.

I tried looking up this issue on the web.I found issues related to add-on signing and something related to versions of firefox (i.e adding extensions is not supported in newer versions of firefox).I went through the known issues on github for GeckoDriver and didn't find much.

Firefox version:- 70.0 (64-bit)
"geckodriver": "^1.19.1",
"selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.3",

```
require('geckodriver')
let webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
let firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox')


let firefoxOptions = new firefox.Options().addExtensions(`${__dirname}/../../../packages/firefox/extension-dev@pixm.net-2.0.0.0-firefox.xpi`)

describe(firefoxBasic[i].name, function () {
    this.timeout(timeOut);
    let driver;
    before(function () {
        mockApi.setAdpFlag(false)
        return new webdriver.Builder()
            .forBrowser('firefox')
            .setFirefoxOptions(firefoxOptions)
            .build()
            .then(d => {
                driver = d;
            });
    });

   // Some more code
})
```

I expect the extension to be attached to the firefox so that i can test the functionality of the extension by running Test cases.

Answer (score 0):

I tried by adding signed extension xpi file and it worked with the same code.
There are ways to sign your extension. Refer below link for more details on how to sign add-ons for firefox.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-on-signing-in-firefox?as=u&utm_source=inproduct